# Source code not wrapping in CKEditor on Firefox

Tags: firefox, ckeditor

When viewing the source code in an instance of CKEditor, the code is not wrapping when using Firefox (version 36.1). I have checked this with the [CKEditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) to make sure it is not my code, and this problem happens there too.

I have checked the demo in Internet Explorer 11, Opera 27.0 and Chrome 41 and the source code wraps in all of these browsers, so why is it not wrapping in Firefox?

I am using Windows 8.1.

Thanks.

Comment: This was reported as an issue. See https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13031

Answer (score 9):

It's a recent change in Firefox and you can fix this by adding to your stylesheets:

```
textarea.cke_source {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Check this [ticket](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13031). This issue will be fixed in next minor CKEditor release.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you Reinmar. I was able to fix this by changing this style in:
ckeditor/skins/moono/editor_gecko.css

```
.cke_source{
font-family:'Courier New',Monospace;
font-size:small;
background-color:#fff;
white-space:pre
}
```

was changed to

```
.cke_source{
font-family:'Courier New',Monospace;
font-size:small;
background-color:#fff;
white-space:pre-wrap
}
```

I changed this in editor.css as well.

Comment: Great, that was helpful, I found the entry right away.

Comment: This same issue is showing up now in Chrome, I think from Chrome 49 just released yesterday (Mar 31 2016).  I made this same pre-wrap CSS update to editor.css (same directory as editor_gecko.css), and that fixed it (I'm still on CKEditor 4.4.3).  Trying the CKEditor Demo (v4.5.8), it already has the updated CSS.

Comment: Note that it may be more effective to add the `.cke_source { white-space: pre-wrap; }` to your own stylesheet, instead of the one for your ckeditor skin, so that you won't have to worry about re-adding it if updating the skins/plugins.